# Browser still shows after setting visibility to False

Tags: excel, browser, vba

I have created a program that scrapes a few webpages for my work.
The program works fine, there is just a little bug I can't seem to fix.

When scraping the pages, I set the browser window to be hidden, using `Browser.Visible = False`.
Sometimes (but not always) the browser will pop up and be visible when the program is running.
It is only visible for a second (as I close it after I'm done with it), but I run this sub about 12 times each time the program is run, so there is a constant Internet Explorer window popping up again and again in the background.
This is an annoyance I'd like to fix as I would like for my boss to use this to help speed up work.

**Excel Version: 2010

IE Version: 8**

Here is my code to open the browser:

```
Sub PullTime(webSite As String, rngTime As Range, rngCase As Range, findMe As String)
Dim Browser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim txt As String
Dim founder As Double
Dim tempBool As Boolean

'Initialize Variables:
tempBool = True
Set Browser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Browser.Visible = False
Browser.Silent = True
Browser.Height = 10
Browser.Width = 10

Application.StatusBar = "Opening page"

Browser.navigate webSite
Do While tempBool
    tempBool = WaitForBrowser(Browser, 0.5)
    founder = founder + 1
    If founder > 10 Then
        MsgBox "Waited for longer than 5 seconds, ending program."
        End
    End If
Loop
Application.StatusBar = "Gaining control over DOM object"
Set HTMLDoc = Browser.document
tempBool = WaitForBrowser(Browser, 0.5)

txt = HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML

'****I MANIPULATE THE TEXT HERE, THEN CLOSE BELOW****

Application.StatusBar = ""
Browser.Quit
Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
Set Browser = Nothing
End Sub
```

The `WaitForBrowser` sub simply waits for 0.5 seconds so the browser can load, and is looped once because it can take a second or two sometimes for the browser to load at that point.

If anyone knows why the browser is still opening even after I have set Visible and even Silent, please let me know!
Please keep in mind this is on a work computer, I don't have access to all security functions or high-tech work-a-rounds.

Comment: two things: 1) doesn't the browser load as invisible by default? I know I usually have to set the visible property = True if I want to see it. 2) if you step through the code at which exact line does the browser become visible again? Knowing at which point it becomes visible will help you determine what may be causing it and how to stop it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! :)
1) You're correct, I added the visible = false to try and stop this as it was popping up (just commented it out and tried again, still popping up without that line)
2) I step through the code and it works fine, the browser is never shown. Which is why I think this may be a bug :/ The problem lies in sometimes it will show, and sometimes it wont, after running the same code. I was wondering if anyone knows any way to 'force' it not to show, or any little missing comma that might be messing it up.

Comment: Try to use `XHR` instead of `IE` for scraping :)